# C++ Correct way to pass a std::unique_ptr object as reference on a function argument

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have a `std::unique_ptr<T>` object and a library function that takes `T&` as a parameter. This function will change `T` object data.

What is the better way to pass the `std::unique_ptr<T>` to that function ? Is the above code correct ? Is there a better approach ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Test {

   public: 
       std::string message = "Hi";
};

void doSomething(Test& item)
{
    item.message = "Bye";
}

int main()
{
     std::unique_ptr<Test> unique = std::unique_ptr<Test>(new Test());

     std::cout << unique->message << " John." << std::endl;

     doSomething(*unique.get());

     std::cout << unique->message << " John." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `*unique` is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard library smart pointers are supposed to be used like raw pointers when it comes to dereferencing the pointer. That is, you'd simply use

```
std::unique_ptr<Test> unique(new Test());
std::cout << unique->message << " John.\n";
doSomething(*unique);
```

I included the declaration to show the simplified use and one output to emphasize [not to use `std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/).

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to call `get`, just dereference:

```
doSomething(*unique);
```

It is best to pass around references to the stored object rather than passing the `std::unique_ptr` around by reference, as the lifetime and storage of an object shouldn't need to be communicated to every function using that object.